# OS-Prober not recognized!

Tags: grub2, bootloader, os-prober

So due to some shenanigans with trying to get rid of all traces of grub-customizer, I accidentally hit "delete" an extra time while in a root nautilus, and deleted my os-prober script in `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`.

So I was about to freak out and come here without doing anything when I realized that everything should be beack if I ran `sudo apt-get purge os-prober` and then `sudo apt-get install os-prober`.  No dice!  It was still gone!  So I ran the same purge/reinstall thing on `grub2`.  Nope!  I have copied over another `30_os-prober` from another Ubuntu install (same version and architecture), and it works when run in terminal by typing `sudo os-prober`, but it isn't picked up when running `sudo update-grub`.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tch.  Problem is mysteriously solved after a restart.  Strange.